# Something unintelligible in javascript

Tags: javascript

What does it mean?

1.

```
a==b&&b={}
```

2.

```
a==b||b={}
```

I didn't find answer

Comment: Look up "javascript operators" for a start. There are many duplicates. There is some "magic" here because of the *short circuit* nature of `&&` and `||`.

Comment: Both yield `ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php

Comment: @pst Even if it is a variable in scope, it throws the ReferenceError.

Comment: You need to add parenthesis, `a==b||(b={})`

Comment: @Esailija I'd say he needs to *avoid* this confusing pattern.

Comment: Why I need to add parenthesis?

Comment: @ŠimeVidas :P yea, it doesn't seem useful

Comment: @user1758424 Where did you stumble upon that pattern? You "need" parens because logical operators (e.g. `&&`) have precedence over assignments, so in `a==b&&b={}`, `{}` is assigned to `a==b&&b`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a==b` is the condition to be tested. The operators `&&` and `||` test the condition very much like a ternary operator but you use it when there's only one condition you need to test, either false `||` or true `&&`. It would be the same as:

```
if ( a == b ) { b = {} } // a == b && ( b = {} )
if ( a != b ) { b = {} } // a == b || ( b = {} )
```

But as Esailija pointed out in the comments, seems like you're missing some parenthesis:

```
a == b || ( b = {} )
```

Comment: Why I need to add parenthesis?
And what is so bad in my question?

Comment: The parenthesis are needed because of the [operator precedence](http://www.scriptingmaster.com/javascript/operator-precedence.asp). Parenthesis are _always_ evaluated first since they have highest precedence. The assignment operator `=` has lower precedence than the or operator `||`.

Answer (score 1):

It means, if a equals b, then set b to an empty object. The second one means more or less the same. The difference is that the first one will not set b to an empty object if a and b are not equal. But the second one will always do that no matter what. That is because the OR operator in javascript continues where as the AND operator will short-circuit.

http://www.openjs.com/articles/syntax/short_circuit_operators.php

Comment: It only works when you put parenthesis around the assignment portion, otherwise due to the order of operations, it will fail.